# Promise on change event

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand how Promise API works.Currently, my idea is when a switch button is pressed/clicked to log some message or do some AJAX, depends on the situation.Which is a perfect example for chaining.Unfortunately, `then` does not work as expected and it logs the message on page load not on **change** event

```
const userID = $(".options").data('id');
let isEnabled = $("#statusToggler").data('status');

function showStatus() {
    if(isEnabled) {
        $('#statusToggler').bootstrapToggle('on', true);
    } else {
        $('#statusToggler').bootstrapToggle('off', true);
    }
}

async function toggleStatus() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve(function () {
            $("#statusToggler").on('change', function () {
                let status = $("#statusToggler").prop('checked');
                if (status === true) {
                    $("#statusToggler").data('status', 1);
                    $('#statusToggler').bootstrapToggle('on', true);
                } else {
                    $("#statusToggler").data('status', 0);
                    $('#statusToggler').bootstrapToggle('off', true);
                }
            })
        });
    });
}

async function ajaxModifyStatus() {
    await toggleStatus()
        .then(function () {
            console.log("Do something when toggle is pressed/clicked");
        });
}

showStatus();
ajaxModifyStatus();
```

Comment: Does it logs to the console?

Comment: With the source code you’ve provided this is a pointless use case for a Promise. None of these calls are asynchronous so you’re just unnecessarily wrapping them within a Promise. I would re-think this approach. A really simple problem to understand Promises is to implement a image lazy loader or something of that nature!

Comment: This...is full of errors and mistakes. To list just a few: async functions automatically wrap the return value in a promise so no need to construct one, resolve takes a value, not a callback, you're calling async functions but not awaiting them, etc. Please find a suitable tutorial, of which there are plenty. We'd be happy to help with any specific novel questions you may find in doing so.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the information.I hope it is understandable.I've just started learning it.I'm going to find a proper tutorial, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On first scan your promise syntax looks fine. The functions are both being called at the bottom of the script which is why they're running on page load.

If you want to have them run on an event you want to give the event the function like it's an argument like `ajaxModifyStatus` rather than `ajaxModifyStatus()`.

Sorry I haven't used jQuery in ages so cant remember how to write it. Here's how you might do with normal js...

```js
let element = document.getElementById('myid')

element.addEventListener('change', ajaxModifyStatus)
// Or...
element.addEventListener('change', async() => {
  let result
  try {
    result = await ajaxModifyStatus()
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
  // Do something with result...
})
```

As the previous comments mentioned you don't necessarily need promises for this to work unless you actually want the result of the Ajax function.

*Note* I've actually written this as async await syntax because it's easier on my phone. Just replace that code with the promise if you want to do it that way.